# Getting Table-of-Content and Page Number to work in Pentaho

Tags: java, pentaho

I am developing a reporting application where a user can select(and order) reports from a list of 100 reports and ask for a master report. This master report should contain all the selected reports in the exact order, with a table of contents listing the (sub)reports included in the master report and correct page number.

I am programmatically creating a MasterReport and adding the selected reports as sub reports to the MasterReport's report footer. Each SubReport's report footer has its pageBreakAfterPrint property set to true so that the subreports come on different pages. The page break seems fine in pdf and excel, but in word the page break has no effect.

However, I am not able to figure out how to add a table-of-content element programmatically to the MasterReport which will list all the subreports added. I would also like to know how to get the page number working properly on page footer programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there is a separate jar that has the TOC code. However, I am still not sure how to use. This doesn't matter anymore as we are looking to move to BIRT.